# git submodule referencing SHA that doesn't exist

Tags: git, git-submodules

I took the following files from rcbops:

https://github.com/rcbops/chef-cookbooks

I moved them internally, copying all of the cookbooks over.

I then edited the [.gitmodules](https://github.com/rcbops/chef-cookbooks/blob/master/.gitmodules) file to point to my local repos.

Between the time that I uploaded the repos internally, and the time I tested my code, the external repos were updated. (Particularly Rabbitmq).

After running my command to download the submodules. I get the following error:

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: c04c57b549c2b79f2df5922aad3a27769234bf5c
Unable to checkout 'c04c57b549c2b79f2df5922aad3a27769234bf5c' in submodule path 'cookbooks/rabbitmq'
```

From what it looks like, it looks like it is referencing an external SHA, but looking on my local repos for that SHA.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `.gitmodule` might not be enough.

A `git submodule update` might be necessary as well.

Check then content of the parent repo:

- `.git/config` to see if the submodule "`chef-cookbooks`" url has been changed
- and `cd .git/modules/chef-cookbooks`: see if `git remote -v` is empty or points to your own submodule repo.

Comment: Git submodule update gave the following error   git submodule update
fatal: reference is not a tree: c04c57b549c2b79f2df5922aad3a27769234bf5c
Unable to checkout 'c04c57b549c2b79f2df5922aad3a27769234bf5c' in submodule path 'cookbooks/rabbitmq`           I did the other things you suggested and noticed that it was pulling the wrong branch in the .config  and there was no modules folder

Comment: @KirstensAmazing no module folder? What git version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.7.1

Comment: @KirstensAmazing ok, it would help if you could upgrade to 1.8+ (1.8.4 being the latest release)

Answer (score 0):

```
git submodule update --remote -f [module name]
```

This will update your submodule to the head